# python command pip install pillow in windows getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
building 'PIL._imaging' extension
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow
    Complete output from command c:\users\anilkumar.vandrangi\desktop\aspire\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ANILKU~1.VAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tr4denzb\\Pil
low\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ANILKU~1.VAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7zffvlgz-record\in
stall-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile: 4 processes
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running egg_info
    writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\anilkumar.vandrangi\desktop\aspire\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ANILKU~1.VAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tr4denzb\\Pillow\\setup.py';exec(comp
ile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ANILKU~1.VAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7zffvlgz-record\install-record.txt --singl
e-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ANILKU~1.VAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tr4denzb\Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have are on x64 bit Windows.

The cleanes way to solve it: 
If you have installed 32 bit version of python: uninstall it
install 64 bit
During setup choose to add python to path
Download 64 bit version of pillow:
http://wp.stolaf.edu/it/installing-pil-pillow-cimage-on-windows-and-mac/
Run the setup file.

Comment: HI 
Thanks for your reply, But it is not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Pip version to see if you have the last version available.

```
C:\ python3 -m pip install --version
```

You can either use python or python3, I used python3 because I have 2.7 and 3.5 on the same disk.

If your version is not the latest update with:

```
C:\ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then now try pip install `Pillow` again:

```
C:\ python3 -m pip install Pillow
```

This time it has to work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the pillow version you're trying to install is incompatible with your python version.

Try upgrading both as a final resort.